# Convert numpy array of floats to integers, replacing NaN values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, type-conversion, nan

I have a float64 numpy array that contains values and also NaN's:

```
[[ 5. nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan  6. nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan  7.  5. nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan  7. nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan  4. nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan  5.  3. nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [ 1. nan nan nan nan nan nan  4. nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan  7. nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan  7. nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan  7. nan  7. nan  6. nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan  7. nan]
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan  6. nan nan nan nan  5.]]
```

I want to convert all the numbers to integers but `np.round` or `np.around` does not quiet seems to do the job. Also, I am unable to change the type of the array because integer type arrays do not support "nan's". How do I do this?

Comment: What's the array dtype supposed to be?

Comment: [`numpy.nan_to_num(arr, copy=False)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html), works on arrays. What value do you want nan replaced with?

Comment: np.round doesn't change the dtype.

Comment: What value do you want NaN replaced with? Zero, or some other specific value?

Answer (score 3):

**To convert NaN to zero:** [`numpy.nan_to_num(arr)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html), works directly on arrays, as well as single values. (Use the `..., copy=False` arg to avoid wasting memory, i.e. operate in-place.)

So to do both the NaN replacement then type-conversion: `numpy.nan_to_num(arr).astype(np.int)`

```
from numpy import array, nan
arr = np.array([[5., nan, nan], [nan, 6., nan], [nan, 7., 5.]])

arr = np.nan_to_num(arr, copy=False).astype(np.int)
array([[5, 0, 0],
       [0, 6, 0],
       [0, 7, 5]])
```

**To convert NaN to any other specific value:**
You didn't say what value you want to replace NaN with. If you want a different replacement value than zero, you'll need to do that using logical indexing: `arr[np.isnan(arr)] = -99` then `.astype(np.int)`.

Answer (score 2):

The question is, to what value should these be converted to?

Let's say this array is names `x`, then:

```
x[np.isnan(x)] = 0 # value you want to replace NaN with
```

And now, you can convert your data to integers the way you wanted to.